# range function doesn't work in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, range

I use jupyter notebook in vscode.
I execute the simple code in Jupyter notebook(.ipynb)

```
a = list(range(10))
print(a)
```

The code execution result is...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-b9f6d3d8e065> in <module>
----> 1 a = list(range(10))
      2 print(a)

TypeError: 'range' object is not callable
```

but, The code is executed well in Python file(.py)

of course, The code execution result is...

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It's an error that I don't understand. I want to avoid not being able to use Jupiter notebook because of this problem. I ask for your help.

Comment: Have you re-defined range before you called it? I know it sounds silly, but many people seem to re-define built-ins because they name their variables that.

Comment: I've never used a code that re-defines range within that cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already defined list,range varable, try to restart your notebook.

```
list = range(10)
>>> list(range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'range' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'm ashamed, but this answer was the answer.

Comment: @duckchun If this is the answer, do you mind to accept it so as to help others in the future?

Comment: I have to wait 3 minutes to accept your answer. So I waited and accepted it.